# How to raise and re-raise in post flop rounds?

Tags: rules

Suppose the flop has been shown. Now the active person to the left of the big blind will check or bet the flop. He bets and then it's my turn and I choose to raise him and then he calls. Now after the turn card has been shown, who will do an action (check/bet/fold), the one to the left of the big blind(as earlier) or me who raised before this?

Suppose if I had only called his bet, then after the turn card has shown, who will act first?

Comment: see also https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/921/trying-to-express-nl-betting-rules-formally-did-i-miss-anything and https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9010/no-limit-holdem-first-bet-after-the-flop?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In hold 'em games, the first to act is the first person to the left of the dealer in all post-flop rounds. They have the option to check or bet. They can fold, but it's generally polite to check and fold to a bet.